# Buffer signals before particular signal occurs

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I wonder if it's possible to accumulate results of signals happening between `next`s of a particular signal. Similar to

```
[[[RACSignal
    combineLatest:@[signal1, signal2, signal3]]
    takeUntil:signal4]
    subscribeNext:^(id x) {
        // ...
    }];
```

But not completing after the first `signal4`'s `next`.

The scenario I'm working with is I have a `viewController1` that presents `viewController2`. `viewController2` allows user to change an `object` that affects data presented in `viewController1`. Currently I'm exposing an `objectChangedSignal` on a `viewController2` and listening to it from `viewController1`.

However, I'd like to receive changes of the `object` directly from the `viewController1` but only after it fires `viewWillAppear` signal and only if changes happened after `viewWillDisappear` of `viewController1`.

Hope it makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to buffer values is to use `-[RACSignal collect]`, which collects them into an array until the signal completes:

```
[[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[ s1, s2, s3 ]]
    collect]
    takeUntil:s4]
```

Howevever, you probably wanted each value to be sent individually on the final signal, not an array of values. You can use `-[RACSignal flattenMap:]` to flatten those values back into the final signal:

```
[[[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[ s1, s2, s3 ]]
    collect]
    takeUntil:s4]
    flattenMap:^(NSArray *collected) {

        return [[collected rac_sequence] signal];

    }]
```

And since you don't want your signal to be completed after `s4`, you can use `-repeat` to resubscribe after every time `s4` sends a value. If you didn't do this, the `-takeUntil:` would cause your signal to complete when that happens.

```
[[[[[RACSignal combineLatest:@[ s1, s2, s3 ]]
    collect]
    takeUntil:s4]
    flattenMap:^(NSArray *collected) {

        return [[collected rac_sequence] signal];

    }]
    repeat]
```

Note that if any of the combined signals are cold signals, the resubscription will cause their side effects to occur additional times. So you may have to convert them into a hot signal by multicasting them (or the combined signal):

```
RACMulticastConnection *mc = [[RACSignal combineLatest:@[ s1, s2, s3 ]] publish];
RACDisposable *d = [mc connect];
[[[mc.signal
    takeUntil:s4]
    flattenMap:^(NSArray *collected) {

        return [[collected rac_sequence] signal];

    }]
    repeat]
```

You may need to explicitly unsubscribe (by disposing `d`) if your signal would otherwise live infinitely.

(Nota bene, this code is untested.)

Comment: Thank you for the extensive answer! But it doesn't really work in a way I imagined; most likely due to the poor description of the task: `s1`, `s2` and `s3` won't necessarily fire. But if they do, I want to be notified only after `s4` fired.

Comment: If any of `s1`, `s2`, or `s3` doesn't send a value, then `-combineLatest:` will never send a value – it waits until each of the signals given to it sends a value before sending the tuple of values. (There are ways of dealing with this, such as using `-startWith:`.)

It also sounds like `-[takeUntil:s4]` is not what you want, since this *completes* the signal when `s4` fires. Perhaps you want one of `-skipUntilBlock:`, `-skipWhileBlock:`, or `-if:then:else:` operations?